# CRUD operation for custom table in umbraco without using admin

Tags: umbraco7

I have created a user Register form by using custom table (own table) in Umbraco 7.2 MVC.

User registration form created by using petapoco method. 
Model code is shown below:

```
[TableName("UserLogin")]
    [PrimaryKey("UserId", autoIncrement = true)]
    [ExplicitColumns]
public class User
    {
        [Column]
        public string UserId { get; set;}

        [Column]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Email",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,3})$", ErrorMessage = "Email is not a valid e-mail address.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Column]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Adress", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Column]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered mobile format is not valid.")]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        [Column]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength =6, ErrorMessage = "please enter minimum 6 character")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Confirm Password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password dose not match.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "please enter minimum 6 character")]
        public string UserConfirmPassWord { get; set; }



    }
```

controller(User controller) code is below for insert

```
public ActionResult AddUser(User _user)
            {
                //Add new user
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    ViewBag.MessageError = "Not Successfully Registration";
                    return CurrentUmbracoPage();

                }

                var db = ApplicationContext.Current.DatabaseContext.Database;
                _user.Password = Encrypt(_user.Password);//Encrypt the password

                db.Insert(_user);
                ViewBag.MessageSuccess = "Successfully Registration Done";
                return Redirect("/home/login/");



            }
```

Data insert and selectr are working, but I need to edit, update, delete the data by id .

I would need controller and view code  for edit, update delete (Umbraco 7.2 using petapoco).

Comment: Could you please show what you tried so far?

Comment: Any particular reason why you didn't use the umbraco member service and add custom properties to it?